# How to show $\exists C \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $f = C\Delta^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

Let $f \in M_k(\Gamma)$ not null in $\mathbb{H}$.

I want to show that there exists a $C \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $f = C\Delta^n$.

I think one can show that for a $k>0$ and $f\in M_k(\Gamma)$ not null in $\mathbb{H}$  f is a cusp form ($\frac{k}{12}$ formula?) and then conclude by induction.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ the full modular group? By the way I think you should change your screen name to something less offensive.